# Inner join using SqlQuery with Entity Framework in MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
var getdata = (DB.books.SqlQuery("select * 
                                  from book 
                                  inner join allclass on allclass.id = book.class_id_fk
                                  inner join universty on universty.id = allclass.universty_id_fk")
              ).ToList();
```

I want to run this SQL query for joining table data in Entity Framework - how can I do this ?

Another way to do this with linq query but i want to get data with SQL query using Entity Framework

Comment: Are you want to convert join query above using LINQ to Entities (either lambda or query expression)? Please explain further what you want to achieve.

Comment: i know how to join with LINQ query but i want to join with sql query as i above write code

Comment: Your sample code already has a SQL query with an `inner join`. I don't understand the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use DB.books if the result of the query is not of type books. You must instead use DB.Database class when the return type of the raw sql is not of any entity type from the database.

Follow these steps:

1) Create a model that matches your list of output columns like below.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Column1{ get; set; }
    public decimal Column2{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

2) Alter your query like below.

```
var getdata = (DB.Database.SqlQuery<List<MyModel>>("select Column1,Column2.. //List all the columns instead of using * 
                                  from book 
                                  inner join allclass on allclass.id = book.class_id_fk
                                  inner join universty on universty.id = allclass.universty_id_fk")
              );
```

Comment: what is mean of DB.database because i dont know this ?

Comment: DB.Database is a class exposed by entity framework. This class has SqlQuery method which should be used while writing raw sqls for non entity types. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql for more details.

Comment: i am exucting this simple query var get = DB.Database.sqlquery<string>("Select * from book").tolist() and getting this error..............The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: In your query you are trying to fetch all the columns of the book table and telling the compiler that the output will be of type string. Please read more from about generics in C# at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/.